# Gyroscope game that detects where device has been bumped from

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

As the title says, I'm working on a simple game that tells you which side are you bumping your device from. For that I must use Gyroscope. What I did was playing with the user acceleration in the x y and z axis, and it seems to work fine. However, there is a "bug". Sometimes when you bump the device from one side - in the x axis, for example -, it will detect more acceleration in a different axis, and the game will tell you that you just bumped the device from a different side than the one you actually did from. I've been trying to fix this with no success at all. I would really appreciate any help or ideas. Thanks in advance. This is my code. A bit long as I check every possible device orientation.

```
public Image BackgroundImage;
public Text Side;
public Button StartRecording;
public Button StopRecording;

private const float TIME_BETWEEN_BUMPS = 1.0f;
private Gyroscope _mGyro;
private string _saveFile;
private float _waitTimeBeforeNextBump;
private float _waitTimeBeforeBlue;
private float _bumpThresholdX = 1f;
private float _bumpThresholdY = 1f;
private float _bumpThresholdZ = 1f;
private bool _isRecording = false;
#endregion

void Start()
{
    _mGyro = Input.gyro;
    _mGyro.enabled = true;

    BackgroundImage.color = Color.blue;

    StartRecording.onClick.AddListener(StartRecordingListener);
    StopRecording.onClick.AddListener(StopRecordingListener);
}

void Update()
{
    if (_waitTimeBeforeBlue > 0)
    {
        _waitTimeBeforeBlue -= Time.deltaTime;
        return;
    }
    BackgroundImage.color = Color.blue;
    Side.text = "";

    if (_waitTimeBeforeNextBump > 0)
    {
        _waitTimeBeforeNextBump -= Time.deltaTime;
        return;
    }

    float x = Input.acceleration.x;
    float y = Input.acceleration.y;
    float z = Input.acceleration.z;

    if (_isRecording)
    {
        _saveFile +=  x + ";" + y + ";" + z + "\n";
    }

    switch (Input.deviceOrientation)
    {
        case DeviceOrientation.FaceUp:
            _bumpThresholdX = 1f;
            _bumpThresholdY = 1f;
            _bumpThresholdZ = 1.7f;;

            if (x < -_bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.green;
                Side.text = "LEFT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (x > _bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.red;
                Side.text = "RIGHT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y < -_bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.cyan;
                Side.text = "DOWN";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y > _bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.yellow;
                Side.text = "UP";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z < -_bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.grey;
                Side.text = "BOTTOM";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z > 0)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.magenta;
                Side.text = "FACE";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            break;
        case DeviceOrientation.FaceDown:
            _bumpThresholdX = 1f;
            _bumpThresholdY = 1f;
            _bumpThresholdZ = 1.7f;

            if (x < -_bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.green;
                Side.text = "LEFT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (x > _bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.red;
                Side.text = "RIGHT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y < -_bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.cyan;
                Side.text = "DOWN";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y > _bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.yellow;
                Side.text = "UP";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z < 0)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.grey;
                Side.text = "BOTTOM";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z > _bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.magenta;
                Side.text = "FACE";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            break;
        case DeviceOrientation.Portrait:
            _bumpThresholdX = 1f;
            _bumpThresholdY = 1.7f;
            _bumpThresholdZ = 1f;

            if (x < -_bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.green;
                Side.text = "LEFT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (x > _bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.red;
                Side.text = "RIGHT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y < -_bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.cyan;
                Side.text = "DOWN";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y > 0)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.yellow;
                Side.text = "UP";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z < -_bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.grey;
                Side.text = "BOTTOM";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z > _bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.magenta;
                Side.text = "FACE";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            break;
        case DeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
            _bumpThresholdX = 1f;
            _bumpThresholdY = 1.7f;
            _bumpThresholdZ = 1f;

            if (x < -_bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.green;
                Side.text = "LEFT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (x > _bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.red;
                Side.text = "RIGHT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y < 0)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.cyan;
                Side.text = "DOWN";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y > _bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.yellow;
                Side.text = "UP";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z < -_bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.grey;
                Side.text = "BOTTOM";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z > _bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.magenta;
                Side.text = "FACE";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            break;
        case DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
            _bumpThresholdX = 1.7f;
            _bumpThresholdY = 1f;
            _bumpThresholdZ = 1f;

            if (x < -_bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.green;
                Side.text = "LEFT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (x > 0)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.red;
                Side.text = "RIGHT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y < -_bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.cyan;
                Side.text = "DOWN";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y > _bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.yellow;
                Side.text = "UP";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z < -_bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.grey;
                Side.text = "BOTTOM";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z > _bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.magenta;
                Side.text = "FACE";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            break;
        case DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            _bumpThresholdX = 1.7f;
            _bumpThresholdY = 1f;
            _bumpThresholdZ = 1f;

            if (x < 0)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.green;
                Side.text = "LEFT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (x > _bumpThresholdX)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.red;
                Side.text = "RIGHT";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y < -_bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.cyan;
                Side.text = "DOWN";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (y > _bumpThresholdY)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.yellow;
                Side.text = "UP";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z < -_bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.grey;
                Side.text = "BOTTOM";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            if (z > _bumpThresholdZ)
            {
                BackgroundImage.color = Color.magenta;
                Side.text = "FACE";
                ResetLastBumpTime();
            }
            break;
    }

}

private void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.skin.label.fontSize = Screen.width / 40;

    GUILayout.Label(string.Format("gravity  {0} - {1} - {2} ", _mGyro.gravity.x, _mGyro.gravity.y, _mGyro.gravity.z));
    GUILayout.Label(string.Format("Input.acceleration  {0} ; {1} ; {2} ", Input.acceleration.x, Input.acceleration.y, Input.acceleration.z));
    GUILayout.Label(string.Format("Input.acceleration  SQR {0}", Input.acceleration.sqrMagnitude));
    GUILayout.Label(string.Format("Rotation rate {0}", _mGyro.rotationRate));
    GUILayout.Label(string.Format("Bump threshold X {0}", _bumpThresholdX));
    GUILayout.Label(string.Format("Bump threshold Y {0}", _bumpThresholdY));
    GUILayout.Label(string.Format("Bump threshold Z {0}", _bumpThresholdZ));
}
private void ResetLastBumpTime()
{
    _waitTimeBeforeNextBump = TIME_BETWEEN_BUMPS;
    _waitTimeBeforeBlue = TIME_BETWEEN_BUMPS;
}
void StartRecordingListener()
{
    _isRecording = true;
    StartRecording.interactable = false;
}
void StopRecordingListener()
{
    _isRecording = false;
    StartRecording.interactable = true;
    Debug.LogFormat("Gyro values output {0}", _saveFile);
    _saveFile = string.Empty;
}
```

}

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the accelerometer not the gyroscope? Gyro is for rotation while accelerometer is for acceleration.

Comment: Yes, I've been told that I'm allowed to use the accelerometer, and so I did. I'll update with my code